# How do tuples work in VS2012 ?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, tuples

Visual studio 2012 features, **tuples** but not variadic templates.

How is this done, how one implements tuples without the use of varadic templates ?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx (see the section entitled "Faux variadics")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a few words, Microsoft did exactly the same thing they did to implement tuple-like datatypes in .NET previously: Creating many versions, each with a fixed number of parameters. Check the .NET documentation.

"How is this done, how one implements tuples without the use of varadic templates" Note that what Microsoft did is the easy way: C++ tuples are a library feature based on many of the most freaking metaprogramming tricks (Variadic templates related) ever done. The implementation of tuples based on variadic-templates (i.e. the implementation of theorically-infinite generic tuples) is not easy at all. I suggest you to read this interesting [article](https://mitchnull.blogspot.com/2012/06/c11-tuple-implementation-details-part-1.html).

Finally R. Martinho Fernandes has a full article series on his blog talking about efficient C++ tuple implementation: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150213003511/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/07/06/optimal-tuple-i.html)