# Test whether a type V is among the types of a tuple<...> without variardics

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, tuples

A typical implementation would be like so :

```
template <typename V, typename T>
struct Is_in_tuple;

template <typename V, typename T0, typename... T>
struct Is_in_tuple <V, tuple<T0, T...> >
{
  static const bool value = Is_in_tuple<V, tuple<T...> >::value;
};

template <typename V, typename... T>
struct Is_in_tuple <V, tuple<V, T...> >
{
  static const bool value = true;
};

template <typename V>
struct Is_in_tuple <V, tuple<> >
{
  static const bool value = false;
};
```

**The problem arises in VS2012** where tuples exist, but variadic templates do not!

Is there a workaround, **a way to perform such tests without variadic templates ?**

Comment: How can a compiler decently support tuples without supporting variadic templates ?

Comment: @BatchyX: Upper limit and automatic generation akin to Boost.Preprocessor.

Comment: @Xeo: I said decent, as in, standard compliant.

Comment: @BatchyX I was also wondering [that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23711040/2567683) as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, I can't test it on MSVC2012 right now.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template<class Needle, class Haystack, int N = std::tuple_size<Haystack>::value>
struct is_any_of
    : std::integral_constant
      <
          bool,
          (std::is_same<Needle, typename std::tuple_element<N-1, Haystack>::type>
           ::value
           || is_any_of<Needle, Haystack, N-1>::value)
      >
{};

template<class Needle, class Haystack>
struct is_any_of<Needle, Haystack, 0>
    : std::false_type
{};

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    typedef std::tuple<int, int, char, int, int> t0;
    typedef std::tuple<int, int, int, int, int> t1;

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_any_of<char, t0>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_any_of<char, t1>::value << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If VS2012 supports tuple_size and tuple_element, you can use them instead (totally untested code):

```
template <typename V, typename T, size_t T_end = std::tuple_size<T>::value>
struct Is_in_tuple
  : std::conditional<std::is_same<V, typename std::tuple_element<T_end-1,T>::type>::value,
                     std::true_type, Is_in_tuple<V, T, T_end - 1>>::type {};

template <typename V, typename T>
struct Is_in_tuple <V, T, 0> : std::false_type {};
```

Comment: The advantage of this version over mine is that it doesn't produce unnecessary instantiations, since it can break instantiating early due to the `std::conditional`. Whether that's faster or not has to be measured of course.

Comment: @dyp: Edited. I don't see why it breaks instantiation. `std::conditional` still requires all of its arguments to be evaluated. I hesitated to include the evaluated tuple element as another parameter to avoid that, but it stinks when the size reachs zero and didn't want to add another template

Comment: A specialization that is used just as a template argument doesn't need to be instantiated (a complete object type is not required). Therefore, `std::conditional<true, complete_type, declared_but_undefined_template<1,2>>::type` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

A completely different approach is based on the size limit.

We rely on the max number of arguments, which is 5 to 10 if I recall correctly.

We write a specialization for each size besides 0 and 1 that invokes smaller sized tuples (half, for min recursion), `||` the result of each half.

Then we write `<T>` and `<>` specializations.

Only fall back on this if other solutions fail, as it stops working the moment you get a standards compliant tuple, or even change the preprocessor symbol of max number of elements for a tuple.